# Set part of a line as variable csh

Tags: text, input, csh

I have started programming in csh just a while ago, and I am having one specific problem.

I have an external input file with the structure:

```
[division]

    [[subdivision1]]

        vara = value1
        varb = value2

    [[subdivision2]]

        anothername = value3
```

I would like to extract the values "value1", "value2", etc, and set them as variables from this format. I know how to read lines, but not how to specify that the variable I want is just "valuei", after the "= ", not the whole line itself.

Edited to add that I know that I can read line by line and then splitting by delimiters, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way.

How could I do it?

Thanks

Comment: This is where I would start recommending a "real" programming language such as Python, Ruby, etc. csh, in particular, has lots of quirks and annoyances that are difficult to work around.

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` over a list of words is the most idiomatic csh way of looping, and this can be used to advantage. The following shows how to use this, with a little state included to check when we have found the tokens *var*, *=* and *value*.

```
set prev =
foreach word (`cat data`)
  if ( "$prev" == "=" ) then
    echo "found var $var = $word"
  endif
  set var = "$prev"
  set prev = "$word"
end
```

will produce

```
found var vara = value1
found var varb = value2
found var anothername = value3
```

which is reasonably clean. The disadvantage is that you can't choose how `csh` splits your words. Thus, if your values contain whitespace there is not really much you can do.